# Use UUIDs as index column in dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, dask, psycopg2

I am trying to create a dask dataframe from a PostgreSQL table using the `dask.dataframe.read_sql_table()` function. However, the index column I am trying to use contains UUIDs as they are the primary keys in my SQL table. Unfortunately, simple queries fail, most likely because SQLalchemy (or psycopg2) fails to sort the UUIDs for partitioning.

Here's some descriptive sample code that is supposed to return the 10 largest scores in my database:

```
from dask import dataframe
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

params_dic = {
    "host"      : "localhost",
    "database"  : "results_db",
    "username"  : "user",
    "password"  : "strongpassword",
    "drivername": "postgresql"
}

url = URL(**params_dic)

ddf = dataframe.read_sql_table("results", url, schema="players",
                               divisions=list("0123456789abcdefh"), index_col="id")

ddf.scores.nlargest(10).compute()
```

This yields the following error:

```
DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type uuid: "0"
LINE 3: WHERE players.results.id >= '0' AND players.re...
                                                  ^

[SQL: SELECT players.results.id, players.results.score, players.results.rank 
FROM players.results 
WHERE players.results.id >= %(id_1)s AND players.results.id < %(id_2)s]
[parameters: {'id_1': '0', 'id_2': '1'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)
```

Comment: Does the error imply that you cannot compare a UUID with a string? You might need to use the (tricky) function API to cast the id column to string.

Comment: It's possible! I'm not sure how psycopg2 deals with hexadecimals under the hood, but the error somehow looks like it. The divisions list btw comes from the official dask documentation in a very similar example: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-sql.html#specific-partitioning
Can you give me a pointer on how to cast the id column before reading it in?

Comment: The docstring has this example: `index_col=cast(sql.column("id"),types.BigInteger).label("id")`. so I suppose you would use type `sqlalchemy.types.String`.